WCF unexpected async behavior
I have a windows service application in .NET 4.6. Inside this windows service, I host a WCF REST API. The API itself exposes an endpoint that makes a call to an external SOAP service (this SOAP service is running on a remote host and is maintained by a different company). The SOAP client for this service is auto generated by adding Service Reference. The setup is the following:
// The data contract

[DataContract]
public class MyDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "M")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

// Service definition

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "mymethod", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Task<MyDto> MyMethod(MyDto input);
}

// Service implementation (async)

//[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] Commented Concurrency mode
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public async Task<MyDto> MyMethod(MyDto input)
    {
        DateTime serviceStart = DateTime.Now;
        
        var client = new MyExternalSoapServiceReference.MyExternalSoapServicePortTypeClient();
        var result = await client.ExternalCall(input.MyProperty);
        input.MyProperty = result.ResponseProperty;

        DateTime serviceEnd = DateTime.Now;
        
        // log serviceStart & serviceEnd timestamps
        
        return input;
    }
}

// Setup wcf host

WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));

/*
Commented throttling behavior

System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttlingBehavior = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1000;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentInstances = 2000;
throttlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1000;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttlingBehavior);
*/

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WebHttpBinding(), "/myapi");

host.Open();

I face problems regarding WCF and the way it handles async operations. It seems that WCF cannot handle properly a batch of concurrent requests. To be more specific, I do not care about the actual processing, rather than the "acceptance" of the requests by WCF. To be more specific, by "acceptance" I mean the moment that WCF starts processing a request, passing the request to my handling method for processing.
To test my WCF endpoint, I have created a sample console app that requests my REST endpoint as following:
// Test client snippet

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await MakeRequest();
    });
    tasks.Add(t);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

private async Task<string> MakeRequest()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
            DateTime clientStart = DateTime.Now;

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:8080/myapi/mymethod", 
            new StringContent(SerializationUtils.SerializeToJsonString(new { M = "1" }),
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json"));

            DateTime clientEnd = DateTime.Now;

    // log clientStart & clientEnd timestamps

    }
}

All operations are async:

client requests are async
service endpoint implementation is async
the call to the external SOAP service is also made async way

At my test client level, I log the clientStart/clientEnd timestamps. At service endpoint level, I also log the serverStart/serverEnd timestamps.
Since all involved operations are async, I would expect that clientStart timestamps should be very close (nearly at same timestamp), meaning that http requests "leave" test client (nearly) at the same time.
In the same fashion, I would expect that serverStart timestamps should be very close as well, meaning that the requests "arrive" to my endpoint (nearly) at the same time.
Experiment 1
Having this setup, I run the 500 concurrent requests and log the timestamps for both client and wcf api. I noticed that only clientStart timestamps are very close. The serverStart timestamps disperse from 1 - 40sec.
Experiment 2
Having the same setup, I replace the external SOAP call
var result = await client.ExternalCall(input.MyProperty);

with this
await Task.Delay(2000); // add an async delay to mock SOAP call

Again, I have the same observations with experiment 1.
Experiment 3
Beginning again with the setup of experiment 1, I enabled throttling behavior (commented lines), in order to have enough limit >> 500 for concurrency, and also uncommented the Concurrency mode attribute (service annotation). Again, I got the same observations with experiments 1 & 2.
Experiment 4
Having same setup with experiment 3, I replaced again the SOAP call with the Task.Delay. I noticed that indeed all 500 requests "arrived" at the same time in wcf endpoint!
Question
My question is about interpreting the results of the four experiments: why do requests not arrive at same time for experiments 1-3? It seems logical to me, that since all operations are async, then WCF should accept the incoming request rate and process the 500 requests concurrently. I don't care about the execution time, since this strictly depends on the external service. I am focusing here only on the "arrival" timestamps of the requests. Shouldn't all 500 requests arrive concurrently?
Another question is about the experiment 4: there seems to be a dependency between the "arrival" of requests in wcf and what the operation involves (actual SOAP call or Task.Delay). It seems logical to me that there should not exists such a dependency at all.
I have also tried the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/wcf/service-scale-up-slowly
which states that there may be a possible issue with earlier WCF implementations about async request handling. I have tried the proposed workaround but I could not see any difference.
Thank you in advance!

I think that you did not add any settings in Experiment 1 and Experiment 2, which may have caused the default service throttling configuration to limit the number of concurrent requests. Then Task.delay will not block the worker thread. This enables the system to handle more concurrent requests because each request does not occupy thread resources while waiting. This effectively improves the system's concurrent processing capabilities and response speed.

I still recommend adding a log trace file to see what's going on. Tracing and Message Logging
